# AWS JS LAMBDA "errorMessage": "The provided key element does not match the schema" error

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a batch job setup in Lambda to load json data into DynamoDB,
My Lambda function code:

```js
onsole.log('function starts')

const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'eu-west-2'})

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback){
    console.log('processing event: ' + JSON.stringify(event, null, 2))


let params =  {
    RequestItems: {
        m2222: [
                    {
                PutRequest: {
                    Item: {
                        rid: event.rid,
                    }
                }
            }
       ]
    },
};

    docClient.batchWrite(params, function(err,data){
        if(err) {
            callback(err, null)
        }else{
            callback(null, data)
        }
    });

}
```

I`m tesitng this function with following test event:

```js
[
  {
    "rid": "b1"
  },
  {
    "rid": "b2"
  },
  {
    "rid": "b3"
  }
]
```

My DB have one Key called rid and is setup as a string:
[DB Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKlnS.png)
Whenever i try to run it it gives me the error:

```css
 "errorType": "ValidationException",
  "errorMessage": "The provided key element does not match the schema",
```

At this point i`m completely clueless in what do i do wrong - the key is the only thing im declaring in this function and the only thing that exists in this database.
Any help is greately appreciated !

Comment: This is obviously for batch loading of json data

Comment: Is the code you pasted exactly what you're running? You're passing in an array, but trying to access `event.rid`; if event is an array, the `rid` property is going to be undefined.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. My understanding is that event.rid is taking value from the parameters i`m passing in the json to the function. So event.rid would be "b1", b2" etc. or am i missing something ?